# How to redefine the footer in bemaer class to show full citation and page number whenever \footfullcite is used

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footer

I am using a latex beamer template that defines a fancy footer. What I wish to do is to replace this footer on every slide where I use `\footfullcite{}` to display the citation generated and the page number. So I do not wish to have an extra footline produced by `\footfullcite` but instead change the actual footer. Is that possible?

I appologize in advance in case the question is not well-posed, it's my first time here. So please let me know how I can improve.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.